# Error in Beacon project

Tags: swift, beacon, nsuuid

```
let region = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: NSUUID(UUIDString: "(the appropriate UUID for my beacons)", identifier: "Estimotes")
```

The above line of code in my project is giving me an error stating:

> init(UUIDString;)' has been renamed to 'init(uuidString:)'

Any solution?

Comment: given that a go- not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift 3.0, "UUIDString" is changed in "uuidString". After the unique UUID for your beacon, you have to insert "as! UUID".
So, you have to change your let like this:

let region = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: NSUUID(uuidString: "79A60506-EC33-44A4-AB5D-304816FEC4E2") as! UUID, identifier: "Estimates")

Original answer: 
[Region for LocationManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39284896/region-for-locationmanager/39286313#39286313)

Answer (score 0):

You need to unwrap the NSUUID that proximityUUID provides

```
let beaconUUID = knownBeacons[i].proximityUUID!.UUIDString
let region = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: beaconUUID, identifier: "Estimotes")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.                                                                                    let beaconsUUID = knownBeacons[i].proximityUUID!."B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D"
   let region = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: beaconsUUID, identifier: "Estimates") it get two errors saying expected member name following and expected declaration

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is a typo, but the code shown:

```
let region = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: 
  NSUUID(UUIDString: "(the appropriate UUID for my beacons)", identifier: "Estimotes")
```

Is missing a closing ) after the NSUUID initializer.  It should look like this:

```
let region = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: 
  NSUUID(UUIDString: "(the appropriate UUID for my beacons)"), identifier: "Estimotes")
```