# Region for LocationManager

Tags: swift, xcode, ibeacon

I'm trying to create a region in order to tell my Location Manager which beacon I care about. I have generated a unique UUID for my beacon using the estimate app. However, I keep getting this error which I can't find a solution to. Could you please help me solve it. I have attached a screenshot below.

Here is the coding in writing:

```
let region = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: NSUUID(UUIDString: "79A60506-EC33-44A4-AB5D-304816FEC4E2"), identifier: "Estimotes")
```

This is the error:

> init(UUIDString:)' has been renamed to 'init(uuidString:)'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in Beacon project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39092364/error-in-beacon-project)

Comment: Why you generating UUID for Beacons. if you default UUID using it will also working with the all beacons. Can you tell me please where are you getting "init(UUIDString:)' has been renamed to 'init(uuidString:)'" error ? because i also done work with beacons.

Comment: @Anand Thanks for your interest! I finally found a solution. I will get in contact with you for any future problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift 3.0, "UUIDString" is changed in "uuidString". After the unique UUID for your beacon, you have to insert  "as! UUID".

So, you have to change your let like this:

```
let region = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: NSUUID(uuidString: "79A60506-EC33-44A4-AB5D-304816FEC4E2") as! UUID, identifier: "Estimotes")
```

Comment: Glad to help you!